# Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined : AGM-MAP

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using google map to pinpoint locations of devices using my app.I am using angular 6 and integrated google map using agm-map library. Everything is working fine but when i  try to set bounds to the map so that map shows every marker i get this error,

```
core.js:1598 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined
    at device-location.view.ts:45
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:3724)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:253)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:191)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:129)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at EventEmitter.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:53)
    at EventEmitter.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit (core.js:3704)
    at map.js:220
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
```

Here you can see my code below,

```
 ngOnInit() {
      this.devices$.subscribe(data => {
        if (data) {
            this.devices = data;
        }
      });
    }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.agmMap.mapReady.subscribe(map => {
      const bounds: LatLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); // HERE GOOGLE UNDEFINED
      for (const dev of this.devices) {
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(dev.latitude, dev.longitude));
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  }
```

This is the line of code where the error occurs,

```
const bounds: LatLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems google is not initialized, try

```
declare const google: any;
```

Or install the Google maps typings

```
npm install @types/google-maps --save-dev
```

Comment: I have already installed @types/google-maps.
I tried but still the same error

Comment: did you ad the reference to index.html

Comment: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=places" async defer></script>